# Ignoring a key while destructing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We can ignore a value while destructing a list:

```js
[a,,...rest] = [1,2,3,4] //2 is ignored here
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(rest); // [3,4]
```

Can we do something similar for dictionaries? I tried, but it gives error:

```js
({ a, , c} = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }); //Unexpected token ',
/* I was expecting a to get assigned 10 and c to get assigned 30 */
```

Is it simply impossible to do the same with dictionaries? If yes, then why such a language design decision? Or it's just the parser incapability?

Comment: Just `({ a, c} = obj)` - the keys *shouldn't* rely on order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```js
({a,c} = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }) 

console.log(a)
console.log(c)
```

The first one works that way because it's a spread in then end.
The second one sees it as a trailing comma.

Comment: `[a,,c,d]` also works for the first example. It has nothing to do with [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @Reyno There is a difference between [a,,c,d] and {a,,c,d}, the latter is a trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that.

```js
({ a, c} = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }); 
console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ignore the key while destructing  the dictionaries/object like below :-

```js
( { a, ...remObj} = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }); 
console.log(a, '   ',remObj);
```